# How to get what was the selected item before combobox changed in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I am in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of a `ComboBox`, and wondering about how to reach the item what was selected before this event triggered (i.e. the original selection before the user selected something else).
Thank you for any help!

Comment: at the end of the event, save the current selection to a variable

Comment: There's nothing inherent in the control that will do that for you.  As @Plutonix suggests, you simply have to remember it yourself, the same way you remember any other data.  If this is something you need to do in more than one place then you could create a custom control that inherits `ComboBox` and adds the new functionality. That would be a `PreviousSelectedItem` property or the like that you would set at the end of an overridden `OnSelectedIndexChanged` method.

Comment: Thank you @Plutonix and jmcilhinney, if I had been able to upvote your comments, I would have done it! I was exactly doing what Plutonix suggested, but didn't find any source that have a more standard solution, so I asked here. Right now I don't have to use it multiply, so I'm saving the actual selection at the end.